# Proof that the continuous part of a spectrum really is "interval like"?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I recently learned about the definition of the continuous part of the spectrum of self adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces. For a self adjoint operator A on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ it goes like this:
\begin{align}\sigma_c(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \text{ran}(A -\lambda \mathbb{1}) \neq \overline{\text{ran}(A -\lambda \mathbb{1})} \}
\end{align}
This is all fair and good. I can see that this is clearly defining some part of the spectrum because the resolvent does not exists. And i can also see that is not something that can be achieved on a finite dimensional vector space. But the question still remains for me if the set we just created is worthy of its name. A "continuous" spectrum should in my opinion really be made up out of open, half open or closed intervals.
But is this really always the case and can we prove this property?

Also: Since we only care about self adjoint operators restricting to the reals for the Eigenvalues is fine for now.

Edit: Terribly sorry. I got mixed up and instead wrote down the definition of the pure point spectrum. Also i actually originally referenced the "purely continuous part" which is also something a bit different as i understand. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Are you familiar with the spectral measure? Continuous spectrum corresponds to the part of the spectral measure that isn't pure point measures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem

Comment: I think your definition of the continuous spectrum is incorrect.  I would swap $=$ with $\neq$ to fix it!

Comment: I just read the Wikipedia entry for continuous spectrum and it made me think that the OP got their impression from there.  However it was probably written by a physicist and I am afraid it is mostly based on physical intuition rather than on solid Math!

Comment: Your definition of continuous spectrum is not correct.

Comment: I realize you have edited your definition of the continuous spectrum, but it is still not correct.  I think it should be $\sigma_c(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \text{ran}(A -\lambda \mathbb{1}) \neq \overline{\text{ran}(A -\lambda \mathbb{1})} =\mathcal{H}\}$.

Comment: @Ruy You may be right. This might just be a physics convention that the author of the material i worked with used but he describes what you reference as the "purely continuous" part of the spectrum. Either way, the answer to the question is satisfactory to me.

Comment: I am glad I could help.  Indeed terminology is not standard, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuous spectrum of an operator may not look like an interval at all.  In fact, it can very well be the Cantor set!
Here is an example:

Let $\mu $ be any positive  Borel  measure on the Cantor set, here denoted by $C$, such that $\mu $ has no atoms
(that is,  $\mu (\{x\})=0$, for all $x$ in $C$) and full support
(that is, $\mu (U)>0$, for all nonempty
open sets $U\subseteq C$).

See below for the construction of such a measure.

Consider the operator $T$ on $L^2(C,\mu )$ given by
$$
  T(\xi )|_x = h(x)\xi (x),  \quad \forall \xi \in L^2(C,\mu ),  \quad \forall x\in  C,
  $$
where $h$ is the function defined on $C$ by $h(x)=x$.

Using [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Multiplication_operator) it follows
that the spectrum of $T$ coincides with its continuous spectrum,  which in turn coincides with the range of $h$,  a.k.a $C$.

---

Here is one way to construct a measure $\mu $ on the Cantor set with the required properties.  First of all recall that
the Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, also known as Bernouli's space.  For a concrete homeomorphism
take
$
  \varphi :\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to C,
  $
given by
$$
  \varphi (x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  x_n3^{-n},
  $$
for every $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots ) \in  \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.

Consider the uniform probability measure $\rho $ on $\{0,1\}$,  given by $\rho (\{0\}) =\rho (\{1\}) =1/2$, and let
$$
  \nu =\prod_{n=1}^\infty \rho
  $$
be the corresponding product measure.  Incidentally $\nu $ is known as the Bernouli measure.

It is well known (and easy to prove) that $\nu $ has no atoms and full support.  Since $\varphi $ is a homeomorphism, it
follows that the push forward measure $\mu := \varphi _*(\nu )$ has the same properties.